# Passing arguments to serializer in rails gem active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I'm having some trouble to migrate from jbuilder to active_model_serializers (AMS v0.9). To construct the previus json I need an other object to be passed as argument into my serializer.

I've seen that there are some options for that, but nothing is working for me.

Here is my controller where I call the serializer:

```
def show
  serialized_profile = ProfileSerializer.new(@profile, root: false,
                                                       scope: current_relationship,
                                                       couple_ser: @couple,
                                                       partners_ser: @partners)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: serialized_profile }
  end
end
```

The `@profile`, `@couple` and `@partner` are set in a `before_action`.

And here is my serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :couple

  def couple
    return nil if serialization_options[:couple_ser].nil?
    serialization_options[:couple_ser]
  end
end
```

The thing is that I am totally sure that my controller has the variable `@couple` when request the show method. However its always throwing null.

I am relatively new in ruby on rails. So could someone help me out?

Just to be aware, I posted only the essential parts of the code to be discussed.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AMS v0.10 you should use '@instance_options' instead of 'serialization_options' in your serializer.

Comment: Hey Joeya, thanks for your answer. 

We are using AMS v0.9, and I've seen that is deprecated this option of passing arguments. 

I will try upgrading soon to v0.10 and see if its working, we didn't upgrade yet because some AMS implementation have broken after upgrading. 

But soon I will upgrade and will update this question.

Answer (score 3):

For v0.9

Have you tried something like this?

```
ProfileSerializer
  .new(@profile, {root: false, scope: current_relationship})
  .as_json({couple_ser: @couple, partners_ser: @partners})
```